# android roulet : inner start image disable when roullet rotate and roullet automatic resize

Tags: java, android, android-animation

I developed one application, in that i have roulette, roulette is rotating very well but,

Problem 1 : roulette have inner image of start, when i click to start , roulette rotate : when roulette rotate i want my start image to go away, and when roulette stop, i want to make it visible again,

Problem 2: i have one image of fix sized roulette, but when roulette rotates it automatically resize, i don't want that, i don't know why roulette is automatically resizing. i want to fix this.

[image]

my code is following :

Code is as per below...

```
    package com.example.roulette_project;

import java.util.Random;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SpinActivity extends Activity {
    boolean clickcount = false;
    ImageView switchon;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_spin);

        switchon = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageSwitchOn);
        final ImageView roullete = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.wheel_image);
        final ImageView innerroullete = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.innerroullete);
        final Animation anim1 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(SpinActivity.this,
                R.anim.wheel_spin_anim);
        final Animation anim2 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(SpinActivity.this,
                R.anim.innner_roullete_animation);
        final Animation anim3 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(SpinActivity.this,
                R.anim.from_middle);
        final View l = findViewById(R.id.flipId);
        final TextView team1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        final TextView team2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        final View full = findViewById(R.id.full_view);
        full.setRotationX(30);
        // innerroullete.setRotationY(30);
        // innerroullete.setRotationX(20);
        // Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        // Point size = new Point();
        // display.getSize(size);
        // int width = size.x;
        // int height = size.y;

        // roullete.getLayoutParams().height=height/2;
        // roullete.getLayoutParams().width=width/2;

        switchon.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
//               int SPLASH_TIME_OUT = 3000;
//               
//               
//                  new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
//           
//                      /*
//                       * Showing splash screen with a timer. This will be useful when you
//                       * want to show case your app logo / company
//                       */
//           
//                      @Override
//                      public void run() {
//                       switchon.setVisibility(View.GONE);
//                      }
//                  }, SPLASH_TIME_OUT);
//                   switchon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


                roullete.startAnimation(anim1);
                // innerroullete.startAnimation(anim2);

                roullete.animate().rotation(2);
//               switchon.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                int i2, i1 = 0;

                Random r = new Random();
                i2 = r.nextInt(2);
                i1 = r.nextInt(360);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "angle = " + getAnswer(i1), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                // float i2 = 360/i1;
                // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "angle = " +i1,
                // Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                Bitmap myImg = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                        R.drawable.roulete_hd);
                roullete.setImageBitmap(myImg);

                Matrix matrix = new Matrix();

                matrix.postRotate(i1);
                l.startAnimation(anim2);
                l.startAnimation(anim3);
                Log.d("ROTATIING :-  ", i1 + ": start");
                Bitmap rotated = Bitmap.createBitmap(myImg, 0, 0,
                        myImg.getWidth(), myImg.getHeight(), matrix, true);

                roullete.setImageBitmap(rotated);




//              for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
//                  if (i % 2 == 0) {
//                      try {
//                          new Thread().sleep(1000);
//                          team1.setText("IND");
//                          team2.setText("PAK");
//                      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
//                          // TODO Auto-generated catch block
//                          e.printStackTrace();
//                      }
//
//                  } else {
//                      team1.setText("PAK");
//                      team2.setText("IND");
//                  }
//
//              }
                if (i2 == 1) {
                    team1.setText("IND");
                    team2.setText("PAK");
                } else {
                    team1.setText("PAK");
                    team2.setText("IND");
                }

            }


        });

    }


    public int getAnswer(int i) {

        if (i >= 17 && i <= 49) {
            return 5;
        } else if (i >= 50 && i <= 81) {
            return 4;
        } else if (i >= 82 && i <= 114) {
            return 3;
        } else if (i >= 115 && i <= 147) {
            return 2;
        } else if (i >= 148 && i <= 180) {
            return 1;
        } else if (i >= 181 && i <= 212) {
            return 11;
        } else if (i >= 213 && i <= 245) {
            return 10;
        } else if (i >= 246 && i <= 278) {
            return 9;
        } else if (i >= 279 && i <= 310) {
            return 8;
        } else if (i >= 311 && i <= 343) {
            return 7;
        } else {
            return 6;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you paste some code?

Answer (score 0):

that's pretty simple, just add a listener to the end of the animation

```
private OnClickListener onClick = new OnClickListener(){
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v){
       v.setOnClickListener = null;
       wheel.animate().addListener(animatorListener)... the rest of your animation
   }
};
```

and then at the end of the animation, remove the listener and re-add the click listener

```
private AnimatorListenerAdapter animatorListener = new AnimatorListenerAdapter(){
   @Override
   public void onAnimationEnd (Animator animation){
         animation.removeListener(this);
         button.setOnClickListener(onClick);
   }
}
```